# Not Displaying images in android app using android studio and ms sql database

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a project - content listing app
 about my app, content is uploading by .NET webapp by using MS Sql server database i need to display the content on mobile app
I am using android studio version 3.5.1

Everything is working fine but images are not displaying. 
In place of images it is showing spinner.

**build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.www.appname"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    dexOptions {
        //incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/jtds-1.2.7.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ftp4j-1.6.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'


}
```

**Gallery Layout xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relContainer">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
            android:id="@+id/spncategory"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spncategory"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--  Recycler View  -->
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="328dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Gallery.java**

```
package com.test.www.appname;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class Gallery extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallerylayout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**RecycleView_ActivityFragment.java**

```
package com.test.www.appname;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class RecyclerView_ActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressDialog pbd;
    ArrayList<String> galleryadpter;
    Set<String> set;
    private static final String MyPref ="" ;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    String Item="";
    int ItemId;
    TextView txtitemid;
    String img;
    String title;
    EditText edtgacustname,edtgamobileno,edtgaemail;
    int imgid;
    String datein="";
    String timein="";
    private Spinner spncategory;
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;
    private Button btnlike,btngasubmit;
    int RegIdNo;
    private final String TAG="GAlleryFragment";
    SharedPreferences prefse;
    private static String navigateFrom;//String to get Intent Value
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallerylayout, container, false);
        connectionClass=new ConnectionClass();
        navigateFrom = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("pass_ga");//Get Intent Value in String
        ItemnameBind itemnameBind=new ItemnameBind();
        itemnameBind.execute("");
        String strtext;
        if(navigateFrom==null){
            strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
            navigateFrom=strtext;
        }else {

            Log.d(TAG,"Not-Success");
        }

        spncategory=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spncategory);
        edtgacustname=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtgacustname);
        edtgamobileno=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtgamobileno);
        edtgaemail=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtgaemail);
        txtitemid=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtitemid);
        Datetime1();
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        btngasubmit=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btngasubmit);
        btnlike=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnlike);
        if (navigateFrom.equals("pass_gallery")) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        }

        prefse =this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPref, MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefse.edit().remove("yourKey").commit();
        btnlike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {

                    set = prefse.getStringSet("yourKey", null);

                    if((set==null)||set.size()==0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Select Image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        galleryadpter = new ArrayList<String>(set);
                        set.clear();
                        spncategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btnlike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        edtgacustname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        edtgamobileno.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        edtgaemail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btngasubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
        });

        //button submit action
btngasubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Savedata();

    }
});



        return rootView;
    }
    public void Datetime1(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        // TODO: Avoid using the abbreviations when fetching time zones.
        // Use the full Olson zone ID instead.
        dateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        datein = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        timein = timeformat.format(c.getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
               getActivity().finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    //Itemname Bind the method

    public class ItemnameBind extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ArrayList listitemname=new ArrayList();
        String Y;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{
                Connection con=connectionClass.CONN();
                if(con==null){
                    Y="Error in connection with SQL server";
                }
                else {
                    String query="Select Category from FD_Category where DataStatus=1";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement=con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()){
                        String itemname1=rs.getString("Category");
                        listitemname.add(itemname1);
                    }
                    Y = "Success";
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Y = ex.toString();

            }
            return Y;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           /* if(pbd.isShowing())
                pbd.dismiss();*/
            if(s!="Success"){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            ArrayAdapter ownnamedapter=new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listitemname);
            spncategory.setAdapter(ownnamedapter);
            ownnamedapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            spncategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Item=spncategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    ItemIdBind itemidbind=new ItemIdBind();
                    itemidbind.execute("");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }

    }
    public class ItemIdBind extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        String Y="";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{
                Connection con=connectionClass.CONN();
                if(con==null){
                    Y="Error with Sql Connection";
                }
                else {
                    String query="Select * from FD_Category where Category='"+Item+"'";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement=con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()){
                        ItemId=rs.getInt("Id");

                    }
                    Y = "Success";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Y=ex.toString();
            }
            return Y;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            if(s!="Success") {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            txtitemid.setText(String.valueOf(ItemId));
            Fetch fetch=new Fetch();
            fetch.execute("");
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }

//save method

    private void Savedata(){
        String custnamega=edtgacustname.getText().toString();
        String Mobilenoga=edtgamobileno.getText().toString();
        String emailidga=edtgaemail.getText().toString();
         /*Set<String> set = prefse.getStringSet("yourKey", null);
                    ArrayList<String> addapterarraylist1 = new ArrayList<String>(set);

                    for (String temp1 : addapterarraylist1) {
                        System.out.println(temp1);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), temp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }*/

        if(custnamega.length()==0){
            edtgacustname.requestFocus();
            edtgacustname.setError("Enter the Name");
        }
        else if(Mobilenoga.length()==0||Mobilenoga.length()<10){
            edtgamobileno.requestFocus();
            edtgamobileno.setError("Enter 10 digit mobile number");
        }
        else if(emailidga.length()==0){
            edtgaemail.requestFocus();
            edtgaemail.setError("Enter the Email Id");
        }
        else {
            InsertGallerydata insertgallerydata=new InsertGallerydata();
            insertgallerydata.execute("");

        }

    }


    public class Fetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String z = "";
        String ownid;

        ArrayList<Data_Model> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pbd=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pbd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pbd.setCancelable(false);
            pbd.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            // pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (pbd.isShowing())
                pbd.dismiss();
            if(r!="Success"){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            try {
            RecyclerView_Adapter adapter = new RecyclerView_Adapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Notify the adapter

}
catch (Exception ex){
    z= ex.toString();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),z,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {//
                    String query="";
                    query = "select Id,ItemName,Image from FD_ItemMaster where CatId='"+ItemId+"' and DataStatus=1 order by Id desc";
                    PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                    ArrayList data1 = new ArrayList();
                    while (rs2.next()) {
                        imgid=rs2.getInt("Id");
                         title = rs2.getString("ItemName");
                          img = rs2.getString("Image");

                        //Convertong Images string to bitmap
                       // byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        //Bitmap decodebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
                        arrayList.add(new Data_Model(title,img,imgid));

                    }

                        z="Success";
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                z = ex.toString();

            }
            return z;

        }
    }

    public class InsertGallerydata extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        String Z="";
       // int CustGaId=imgid;
        String Itemnumber;
        int CatGaId=ItemId;
        String custnamega=edtgacustname.getText().toString();
        String Mobilenoga=edtgamobileno.getText().toString();
        String emailidga=edtgaemail.getText().toString();



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try{
//Set<String> set=prefse.getStringSet("yourKey", null);
             //   galleryadpter=new ArrayList<String >();
                for(String temp:galleryadpter){
                    Itemnumber=temp;
                    Connection con=connectionClass.CONN();
                    if(con==null){
                        Z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                    }
                    else {
                        String query = "";
                        String Like="L";

                        query = "Insert into FD_Enquiry(ItemId,CategoryId,CustName,CustMobileNo,CustEmailId,EnqDate,TypeOf)values('" + Itemnumber + "','" + ItemId + "','" + custnamega + "','" + Mobilenoga + "','" + emailidga + "','" + datein + "','"+Like+"')";
                        PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement(query);
                        pr.executeUpdate();
                        // super.onPostExecute(s);
                        Z = "success";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Z= ex.toString();
            }

            return Z;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(!s.equals("success")){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Fetch fe=new Fetch();
                fe.execute("");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Successfully..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spncategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnlike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edtgacustname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                edtgamobileno.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                edtgaemail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btngasubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                reset();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
    void reset(){
        edtgacustname.setText("");
        edtgaemail.setText("");
        edtgamobileno.setText("");
        galleryadpter.clear();
        set.clear();

    }


}
```

**RecyclerView_Adapter**

```
package com.test.www.appname;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
//import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class RecyclerView_Adapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {// Recyclerview will extend to
    // recyclerview adapter
    private ArrayList<Data_Model> arrayList;
    ArrayList<String> gallerylist=new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;
    private final String TAG = "Recycleview";
    ImageView imageDetail;
    String itemId;
    int j;
    String MyPref;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    PointF startPoint = new PointF();
    PointF midPoint = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    private SharedPreferences prefse;
    private String prefName = "";

    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

    // The system "short" animation time duration, in milliseconds. This
    // duration is ideal for subtle animations or animations that occur
    // very frequently.
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;

    public RecyclerView_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Data_Model> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != arrayList ? arrayList.size() : 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Data_Model model = arrayList.get(position);

        final RecyclerViewHolder mainHolder = (RecyclerViewHolder) holder;// holder

        // Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),model.getImage());// This will convert drawbale image into
        // bitmap
        // mainHolder.imageview.setImageBitmap(model.getImage());

        // setting title
        mainHolder.title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        mainHolder.txtimgid.setText(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getTxtimgid()));
        Picasso.with(this.context).invalidate(model.getImage());
        Picasso.with(context)

                .load(model.getImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_images) //
                .error(R.drawable.loading_images) //
                .into(mainHolder.imageview);
        final File url= new File(model.getImage());
        final String path=url.toString();
        final String rel = path.replace("http:/","http://");
        mainHolder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(context, ImageZoomGalleryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("img_urlgallery",rel);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
       // mainHolder.imageview.setImageBitmap(arrayList.get(position).getImage());
        mainHolder.chekitem.setChecked(false);
        itemId=mainHolder.txtimgid.getText().toString();
        mainHolder.chekitem.setTag(arrayList.get(position));

       // holder.chekitem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);


        mainHolder.chekitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public static final String MyPref = "";

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean isChecked = mainHolder.chekitem.isChecked();
                String itemId1 = mainHolder.txtimgid.getText().toString();
                prefse = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPref,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefse.edit();
                Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
                try {
                    restart:
                    if (isChecked) {
                        gallerylist.add(itemId1);
                        for (j = 0; j < gallerylist.size(); j++) {
                            set.addAll(gallerylist);
                            edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
                            edit.commit();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Check Box is selected");
                         //   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox: " + gallerylist.get(j), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                    } else {
                        for (int k = 0; k <= gallerylist.size(); k++) {
                            if (gallerylist.get(k).equals(itemId1)) {
                                gallerylist.remove(k);
                                edit.remove("yourKey");
                                set.addAll(gallerylist);
                                edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
                                edit.commit();
                                Log.d(TAG, "Check Box is NOT selected");
                                /*Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Uncheck on Checkbox: is "
                                        , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                                break restart;
                            }

                            //checkBox clicked and unchecked

                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        // This method will inflate the custom layout and return as viewholder
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

        ViewGroup mainGroup = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, viewGroup, false);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) mainGroup.findViewById(R.id.image);
        final TextView title = (TextView) mainGroup.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final CheckBox chekitem = (CheckBox) mainGroup.findViewById(R.id.chekitem);
        chekitem.setChecked(false);
        /** * set on touch listner on image */


        RecyclerViewHolder listHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(mainGroup);

        return listHolder;

    }



}
```

**RecyclerView_Holder**

```
package com.test.www.appname;

//import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    // View holder for gridview recycler view as we used in listview
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView imageview;
    public CheckBox chekitem;
    public TextView txtimgid;




    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        // Find all views ids

        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        this.chekitem=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chekitem);
        this.txtimgid=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtimgid);

    }



}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure that you can fetch data in `Fetch` task?

Comment: yes, i added full code please check